# Can admin of the web server see my php code?

Tags: php, email, security, web, server

I am making a form that will send the information to my email and I need to take another email to send that form to the main email (using PHPMailer). So in my php code, I have put the password of the 2nd email in it. I will upload my code files to the server. Can admin of the web server have ability to see the variables in my code?

Comment: Yes, he can and even can change it!

Comment: So what can I do to make my information secure?

Comment: Don't use your personal email account.

Comment: Do you secure from most people or secure from admins?  First, can be done. Second, err - no. However, the company that employs that admin has far more serious issues than your email password if the admin decided to do anything to break privacy issues. ;-/ i.e. Don't bother about what the admin can see as regards your code. I assure you they are not interested until it goes wrong and affects the server.

Comment: ok, I understand. I can trust the server now. thank guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course that they can... because they have root level access to your files.

Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PemsuAfc7Jw) and you will understand how PHP works.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. You can assume anyone with admin (root) level access to the server can read whatever file he wants.